# UITableView selection indicator/indenting

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I set up my tableView without the interface builder/storyboard. It works perfectly, but when I use selection the cells are shifting to the right and it shows a checkbox to indicate the selection. Is it possible to get rid of the indentation and the checkbox somehow with code only?
Changing the colour of the selected cells is enough for me.[image]

Comment: Are you using `editingStyle`. That's the one. Else, you can change the color with when the selection occurs by checing if the tableView currently on isEditing or not

Comment: Can you post your table view initialization and data source code?